# block scope resolution in c++ language

Tags: c++, scope

I was doing an exercise in c++ program and i am posting here a part of that program which is giving me problem.

```
int max=100;
main()
{ int max=50;
 {
  int max=25;
  printf("%d",max);
  printf("%d",::max);
  //output will be 25 and 100
 // I wanted to use value "50" of max in this block i.e. the max variable of above block which is local to main
 // and I can't figure out how to do this.
 }
}
```

I know the :: operator does overwrites the priority of local with Global for the statement it is used but i want to do it for one block level up. Please Help me on this. I saw some references in book and on internet too, Actually i did reverse(first on internet and then in books) but i wasn't able to figure it out. Please help me on this.

My original piece of code is:

```
int max=100;
void main()
 {
   int max=50;
   char str[50];
   gets(str);
   if(strlen(str)>5)
    {
     int max=25;
     cout<<"Max here is"<<max<<endl;
     cout<<"Max above was"<</*max value of above block*/;
     cout<<"Max Global"<<::max;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `::` is clearly [tag:c++] not [tag:c]!!

Comment: `::` doesn’t really exist in C.

Comment: Why not just use different names?

Comment: There is nothing like a scope operator for blocks.

Comment: main() without returntype doesn't work... so what is the actual code giving you problems?

Comment: I've added the code piece and I am sorry for the c program title my "plus" key is bad, I apologize for that sir. and I was trying to get the variable value in the other block cause i know nothing is impossible in a program. I wanted to know can i use max with some operator to get the value or i'll have to use pointers only for this purpose. I am avoiding pointers cause they give me nightmares in day. and I am also sorry for late reply cause i was asleep cause its night here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Inner local scopes completely shadow outer nesting scope names.

The best you can do is to make an alias before you shadow the outer name:

```
int max = 100;

int main() {
  int max = 50;
  {
    int &m_max = max; // make reference alias first!
    int max = 25;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", max, m_max, ::max); // have to use alias name :(
  }
}
```

Comment: Applies for [tag:c++] at least (`int &m_max = max; `). Originally the post was tagged [tag:c], and also the title still asks for _'c-language'_.

Comment: True, but he's using `::` to access `::max`, so this has to be C++ regardless of the post title.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked the OP to clarify, which they didn't do yet. Otherwise your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do the second declaration of variable max visible in the inner block because the variable with the same name in the inner block hides it. You can use qualified names only with variables declared in namespaces or class scopes.
In your example you are using qualified name `::max` that to access the variable declared in the global namespace.